# pip install enum not working showing the error of 'intflag' doesnt have

Tags: python-2.7, enums, jupyter-notebook

pip install Enum 
is not working is showing the error of
AttributeError:module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enum34` is the stdlib `Enum` backport, but it only supports features found up to 3.5.  If you want features found in 3.6 you'll need to use `aenum`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.