# AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, installation, enums, python-3.6

While installing any modules on Python in windows 10 I am getting this error. I tried to install numpy buI got this error.
[This is the screeshot of the error o got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Epez.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag)

Comment: It is not advised to add links to the screenshots. It is much better to copy the error stack trace into the question.