# attribute error when creating virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtualenv with the python3.6 interpreter. Just running `virtualenv <env name>` works fine, but creates an env with the 2.7 interpreter. When I try again with the command `virtualenv -p <path to 3.6> <env name>` I get the error `Attribute error: module enum has not attribute Intflag`. I'm not sure how to interpret this error or how to solve the issue.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The way you use for creating the virtualenv is correct. It seems like an issue with Python3.6 interpreter. Try to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45716067/4820341) and let us know!

Comment: I tried the answer to that question and I actually get the same error as in my original question