# cannot uninstall enum34 (Python 3.6, MacOS)

Tags: python, enums, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to open my jupyter notebook with Conda Python3.6. When I try to open it, I'm getting this error

```
VikMacBook-Pro:~ vik$ /anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
 Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 541, in <module>
    main()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 522, in main
  known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 282, in 
addusersitepackages
     user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 258, in 
getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 608, in 
get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 587, in 
get_config_vars
    import _osx_support
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_osx_support.py", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

And I have attempted to solve by following this [endorsed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag), using command

> pip uninstall enum34

However, I'm still getting the following error after running this command

```
Vik-MacBook-Pro:~ vik$ pip uninstall enum34
Skipping enum34 as it is not installed.
```

I do not have my own code file named enum.py

Comment: Are you invoking the correct pip? Run `which pip` to see where it is installed, and `pip --version` to see the version number.

Comment: `Vik-Pro:python_cheatsheets vik$ which pip
/anaconda3/bin/pip
Vik-MacBook-Pro:python_cheatsheets vik$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)` @DietrichEpp

Answer (score 0):

try using "pip3 uninstall enum34" it worked for me