# module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' when creating virtualenv using python3.6?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm runing

```py
$ virtualenv -p `which python3.6` env_pcl

#Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
```

to create an virtualenv by `python3.6`

but an error appeared like below:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 8, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/base64.py", line 9, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

How can I do to avoid it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+%27IntFlag%27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is probably a duplicate of [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23842713/5378816)

However, do you need to use the third party `virtualenv`?

In recent python 3 versions there is a standard [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/venv.html) module. It is the recommended way to create virtual environments since version 3.5.

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helped, but can you still give me some advise about solving my problem with `virtualenv ` above?

Comment: @jiaJimmy Unfortunalely I cannot directly answer your question. Didn't the linked question help? It mentions also a bug in an older verions.