# AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' - fastai install

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

When I try install `fastai` (`pip install fastai`) i get following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

Full traceback:

```
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-b8vreosn/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'':
  ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  Error in sys.excepthook:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
      if not enabled():
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

  Original exception was:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-b8vreosn/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Enum34 cause issues in many packages.I tried to solve this by using:

`pip freeze | grep enum34`

and

`pip uninstall -y enum34`

also i tried `unset PYTHONPATH` and I still get the same error.

`pip show enum34` <-- this command give: `WARNING: Package(s) not found: enum34`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## PROBLEM SOLVED:

as I wrote earlier Enum34 cause issues in many packages.

If you have a similar problem, just use:

`pip uninstall -y enum34`

My problem was that in my case I should use:

`sudo pip uninstall -y enum34`