# sklearn_extra installation issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation, package, sklearn-pandas

[in]:

```py
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
```

[out]:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_extra'
```

Then, I tried installing sklearn_extra via

[in]:

```py
python -m pip install sklearn_extra
```

[out]:

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn_extra (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sklearn_extra
```

Then, I went to installation part of the website(https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and did what it said:

```
Installation
Dependencies
scikit-learn-extra requires,

Python (>=3.5)

scikit-learn (>=0.21), and its dependencies

Cython (>0.28)

User installation
Latest development version can be installed with,

pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip
```

[in]:

```py
pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip
```

[out]:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' 'c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yopprv13\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.28' numpy==1.14.5
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\main.py", line 8, in <module>
      import locale
    File "c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

I checked versions of Cython,Python and sklearn they satisfy the required range.

Edit: the solution is to uninstall enum34 for me thanks to Balraj Ashwatt's comment.

```py
pip uninstall -y enum34
```

Then I was able to install sklearn_extra

Comment: Can we get the full logs?

Comment: These links might help: 1) https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1995#issuecomment-496661430 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag 3)

Comment: Are you sure you have installed into proper environment? Messed with `jupyter` recently because of install to system python instead of project one

Comment: @A.Ametov I think I did the problem is solved with command pip uninstall -y enum34 on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling enum34 worked for me and then I was able to install sklearn_extra

```py
pip uninstall -y enum34
```

Answer (score 14):

I tried,

`pip install scikit-learn-extra`

this seemed to work alright for me 
!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn-extra
```