# i tried to install pyinstaller with pip install pyinstaller and got this:

Tags: python, windows

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w25qgekk\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "main", mod_spec)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip__main.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal__init.py", line 4, in <module>
      import locale
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Pasquale\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w25qgekk\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag

Comment: ohh ty very much