# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:..." when I try to install Keras

Tags: python, linux, keras, installation, nvidia-jetson

I'm using Linux on an Nvidia Jetson TX2, and I'm trying to learn machine/deep learning.
When I try to install Keras, I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

Here are the screenshots of the full error:
[image]

[image]

I just got the TX2 yesterday, and only flashed it. I also have tensorflow installed, as well as python. 
I also tried running these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libatlas-base-dev gfortran
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

followed by `$ sudo pip install keras`.
I have also tried `$ sudo -H pip install keras` and still the same error.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45716067/12896974   Next time, please parse the trace log instead of putting a screenshot of it ;)

Comment: yea sorry about that, and thank you!