# SQLAlchemy installation fails with `module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, installation, python-3.6

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

It gives me that error

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-z5g_5ku8/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (39 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  Error in sys.excepthook:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
      if not enabled():
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

  Original exception was:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-z5g_5ku8/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

i know my question is **bad** but i tried

```
pip3 install SQLAlchemy
pip install -U SQLAlchemy
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo apt install python-setuptools
sudo apt install python-dev -y
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have enum installed. It's a legacy library and not required. You can probably fix your error with:

```
pip uninstall -y enum34
```