# How to install websocket in with pip3?

Tags: python, websocket, pip

I got the following error. Does anybody know how to install it correctly? Thanks.

```
$ pip3 install websocket
Collecting websocket
  Using cached websocket-0.2.1.tar.gz (195 kB)
Collecting gevent
  Using cached gevent-20.5.2.tar.gz (5.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-u69lfxee/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet>=0.4.14 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/tmp/mktemp/pip-build-env-u69lfxee/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet>=0.4.14 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag

Comment: There are many answers. Please be specific which one should be tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+IntFlag

Answer (score 0):

It's because your enum is not the standard library enum module. You probably have the package enum34 installed.

One way check if this is the case is to inspect the property enum.**file**

```
import enum
print(enum.__file__)  
# standard library location should be something like 
# /usr/local/lib/python3.6/enum.py
```

Since python 3.6 the enum34 library is no longer compatible with the standard library. The library is also unnecessary, so you can simply uninstall it.

pip uninstall -y enum34
If you need the code to run on python versions both <=3.4 and >3.4, you can try having enum-compat as a requirement. It only installs enum34 for older versions of python without the standard library enum.

Comment: I see this `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/enum.py`. So it is not the cause of the problem?