# Pyinstaller: AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I need to compile python code to exe. I've found some guide how to do it, where I was asked to install PyInstaller for that:

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

But I get the next error:

```
C:\Users\alonat>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\alonat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yo59g2oq\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (14 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    File "c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 5, in <module>
      import locale
    File "c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
      import re
    File "c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
      class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
  AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\alonat\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\alonat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-yo59g2oq\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Do you know how to resolve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+%27IntFlag%27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please uninstall enum34 module if have installed and try again.

```
pip uninstall enum34
```

this will solve the error,
if you need enum34 downgrade it to enum34==1.1.8

useful info here
[Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag)
https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1995