# AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' from Azure

Tags: python, django, azure

I have a Django project running on Azure, and I encountered this issue with the enum module and I have tried everything from
here([Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag))

The problem is that I don't have the issue locally, I only see the issue on Azure. Therefore, I cannot just uninstall it locally. I have tried to uninstall it in the Azure terminal, but it showed that the module was not found. I have also tried to install aenum instead of enum by adding it to requirements.txt, still didn't work.

Can someone PLEASE advise me on how to fix this issue?

[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYtQi.png)

[Here is the link to the source code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GIynBAefXGDFiNGYpz32GDG77RRuQu7d?usp=sharing) In the folder, the problem occurred after we added "search".

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post both the relevant code and the full traceback error.

Comment: When you say "I have tried to uninstall it in the Azure terminal", which terminal? Kudu console of app service? Also you shared code is missing the `requirements.txt` which I want to have a look.

Comment: I did the SSH under Development Tools in Azure. And I changed the shared code to the entire folder which includes requirements.txt. Initially, I only had a search folder because the problem occurred after we added that folder.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything that is not clear with the question!