# Python Flask Azure Linux WebApp fails with AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Python Flask Azure Linux WebApp fails with below error.
This error is caused after importing the kiteconnect library.
As enum32 is the prerequisit for the kiteconnect, it installs that along with kiteconnect. I have manually uninstalled it via YAML script. I also have attached the screenshot of successful uninstallation along with YAML Script file.

Source Code :

```
from flask import Flask, request
 from kiteconnect import KiteConnect
    
 app = Flask(__name__)
    
 @app.route('/')
 def index():
     Zerodha_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX"
     Zerodha_API_SECRET= "XXXXXXXXXXX"
     Zerodha_Access_Token= "XXXXXXXXXXX"
     kite = KiteConnect(api_key=Zerodha_API_KEY)
     kite.set_access_token(Zerodha_Access_Token)
     data = kite.orders()
     print(data)
     return str(data)
```

Error :

```
2021-07-15T11:12:09.280237068Z 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280292471Z _____ 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280304271Z / _ \ __________ _________ ____ 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280311872Z / /_\ \___ / | \_ __ \_/ __ \ 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280319472Z / | \/ /| | /| | \/\ ___/ 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280326672Z \____|__ /_____ \____/ |__| \___ > 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280334173Z \/ \/ \/ 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280341373Z 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280348073Z A P P S E R V I C E O N L I N U X 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280354874Z 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280361474Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280368174Z Python 3.8.6 2021-07-15T11:12:09.280374875Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted 2021-07-15T11:12:09.654320473Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd. 2021-07-15T11:12:09.739608672Z App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect 2021-07-15T11:12:09.740706500Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite 2021-07-15T11:12:09.871149910Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it... 2021-07-15T11:12:09.881601967Z Build Operation ID: |8ufRzjfGT4Q=.9903ac7b_ 2021-07-15T11:12:09.890669690Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20210420.1, Commit: 85c6e9278aae3980b86cb1d520aaad532c814ed7, ReleaseTagName: 20210420.1 2021-07-15T11:12:09.891252705Z Output is compressed. Extracting it... 2021-07-15T11:12:09.895295404Z Extracting '/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz' to directory '/tmp/8d94707cb81be1f'... 2021-07-15T11:12:14.577736859Z App path is set to '/tmp/8d94707cb81be1f' 2021-07-15T11:12:16.276763516Z Detected an app based on Flask 2021-07-15T11:12:16.278429174Z Generating gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
2021-07-15T11:12:16.836063591Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2021-07-15T11:12:17.568867477Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8d94707cb81be1f/antenv.
2021-07-15T11:12:17.569943514Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ':/tmp/8d94707cb81be1f/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
2021-07-15T11:12:17.674962252Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-15T11:12:17.675003253Z File "/opt/python/3.8.6/bin/gunicorn", line 3, in <module>
2021-07-15T11:12:17.675027254Z import re
2021-07-15T11:12:17.675036154Z File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 145, in <module>
2021-07-15T11:12:17.675044155Z class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
2021-07-15T11:12:17.675051755Z AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
2021-07-15T11:12:25.447Z ERROR - Container rocketzerodha_0_7bea6f30 for site rocketzerodha has exited, failing site start
2021-07-15T11:12:25.461Z ERROR - Container rocketzerodha_0_7bea6f30 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2021-07-15T11:12:25.475Z INFO - Stopping site rocketzerodha because it failed during startup.
```

As suggested by Grace, I uninstalled the enum32 via YAML Script. This is also not helping as the error remains same.
[YAML Script for uninstallation proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmsqp.png)

```
# Python to Linux Web App on Azure
# Build your Python project and deploy it to Azure as a Linux Web App.
# Change python version to one thats appropriate for your application.
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: 'ea695c8e-016a-42de-9492-868b1f100d6b'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'RocketZerodha'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'RocketZerodha'

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  # Python version: 3.9
  pythonVersion: '3.9'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        pip freeze
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip uninstall -y enum34  
        pip freeze
          
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'
          
          - script: |
              pip freeze
              pip uninstall -y enum34  
            
            workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
            displayName: "Install requirements"

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : RocketZerodha'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two different errors here.

For the *module 'enum'* error you might want to uninstall `enum34` if you have it. It's known for causing package issues. See [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag) for more info. Use this command to uninstall: `pip uninstall -y enum34`

Based on the second error message, it looks like port 8000 is not exposed that is why your container is not responding to HTTP pings. Try setting both PORT and WEBSITES_PORT to 8000 in the configuration. You can set the PORT variable in the Azure portal. *App Service -> Configuration -> Application settings -> + PORT 8000*
([source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34451))

[Why Python 3.6.1 throws AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124775/why-python-3-6-1-throws-attributeerror-module-enum-has-no-attribute-intflag)

Comment: Hey Grace, Thanks for the input. I have successfully uninstalled the enum34 via YAML File thru Azure DevOps Pipeline. Even after that the error does not go away.

Comment: YAML File : - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        pip freeze
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip uninstall -y enum34  
        pip freeze