# How to return an array inside of a function?

Tags: python, django

I created a class in my Django project and I call it from views.
I need a result of a function in this class but I cannot return the array. I tried to equalize a array from outside but it returns:

```
<module 're' from 'C:\\Users\\edeni\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\re.py'>
```

How can I use this array in my views?

**views.py**

```
    def setup_wizard(request):
      ...
      functions.myClass(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
                                              setup.n_url, setup.n_port, setup.db_password,
                                              username=request.user.username)
```

**functions.py**

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password, username):
        ...
        self.elastice_yolla(username)
        ...

        def elastice_yolla(self, username):
            self.report_final = []
            array_length = len(glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"))
            self.static_fields = dict()
            for in_file in glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"):
                try:
                    i = 0   
                    with open(in_file) as f:
                        if os.path.getsize(in_file) > 0:
                            np = NES2(in_file, self.index_name, self.static_fields, username)
                            report_final = np.toES()
                            time.sleep(0.02)

                    i = i + 1
                except:
                    pass

        print("report")
        print(report_final)

class NES2:
  def __init__(self, input_file, index_name, static_fields, username):
  ....

  def toES(self):
    ...
    for ...
        for ...
                            try:
                                if bas['cve']:
                                self.es.index(index=self.index_name, doc_type="_doc", body=json.dumps(bas))
                                rep_result.append(json.dumps(bas))
                            except KeyError:
                                pass
  return rep_result
```

Comment: I think the code is right. But you should not mention the module name as file name. Also, are you using anaconda?

Comment: @SivaSankar I am using pycharm

Comment: No, anaconda is a distribution of python. If it is installed, we don't have to install python separately. Would you post the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: there is not enough here to reproduce your issue... so there is also unlikely to be enough here to answer your question

Comment: @SivaSankar there is no error trace. Just I am printing and this returns.

Comment: @JoranBeasley What should I add it? I am sorry I cannot understand

Comment: Don't add it. I asked if in case it is installed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57595192/11282077 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/63008197/11282077 try these links. Issue is related to pycharm.

Comment: @SivaSankar I check it and my setting is the same

Comment: @edche did you check the other answers in that url. Issue is not related to python or django. It is related to the Pc (windows, Mac, vista), python path and python.

Comment: @SivaSankar Actually everything just works fine. For example, when I print rep_result inside of the function it is true. I should move the result outside of the scope. Maybe if is there an alternative solution it can work too.

Comment: if you need result from function then you should use `return`

Comment: did you put `elastice_yolla` inside `__init__` ? It is wrong idea. It should be in class but outside `__init__` and then you should first create instance `item = functions.myClass(...)` and later run `result = item.elastice_yolla()` in `setup_wizard`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your real problem but I think you should organize code in different way.

`elastice_yolla()` shouldn't be defined inside `__init__` and it shouldn't be executed in `__init_`, and it should use `return report_final`

And then in `setup_wizard` you can creat instance and run `elastice_yolla()`

```
my_object = functions.myClass(...)
report = my_object.elastice_yolla()
```

---

```
def setup_wizard(request):
      ...
      my_object = functions.myClass(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
                                              setup.n_url, setup.n_port, setup.db_password,
                                              username=request.user.username)  

      report = my_object.elastice_yolla()
```

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password, username):
        ...
        # self.elastice_yolla(username)
        ...

    # outside `__init__`
    def elastice_yolla(self, username)
        report_final = []
        
        array_length = len(glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"))
        self.static_fields = dict()
        for in_file in glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"):
            try:
                i = 0   
                with open(in_file) as f:
                    if os.path.getsize(in_file) > 0:
                        np = NES2(in_file, self.index_name, self.static_fields, username)
                        report_final = np.toES()
                        time.sleep(0.02)

                i = i + 1
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Exception:', ex)

        return report_final
```

---

Eventually you could run `elastice_yolla` inside `__init__` and assing result to class variable with `self.` and then other function can get this value

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password, username):
        ...
        self.report_final = self.elastice_yolla(username)
        ...

    # outside `__init__`
    def elastice_yolla(self):  # use self.username
        report_final = []

        array_length = len(glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"))
        self.static_fields = dict()
        for in_file in glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"):
            try:
                i = 0   
                with open(in_file) as f:
                    if os.path.getsize(in_file) > 0:
                        np = NES2(in_file, self.index_name, self.static_fields, self.username)
                        report_final = np.toES()
                        time.sleep(0.02)

                i = i + 1
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Exception:', ex)

        return report_final
```

```
def setup_wizard(request):
      ...
      my_object = functions.myClass(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
                                              setup.n_url, setup.n_port, setup.db_password,
                                              username=request.user.username)  

      report = my_object.report_final   # get from variable, not from function.
```

---

Or you should use `self.report_final` in `elastice_yolla`

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password, username):
        ...
        self.elastice_yolla(username)
        ...

    # outside `__init__`
    def elastice_yolla(self):  # use self.username
        self.report_final = []  # <--- self.

        array_length = len(glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"))
        self.static_fields = dict()
        for in_file in glob.glob(self.location + "\*\*.nessus"):
            try:
                i = 0   
                with open(in_file) as f:
                    if os.path.getsize(in_file) > 0:
                        np = NES2(in_file, self.index_name, self.static_fields, self.username)
                        self.report_final = np.toES()  # <--- self.
                        time.sleep(0.02)

                i = i + 1
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Exception:', ex)
```

```
def setup_wizard(request):
      ...
      my_object = functions.myClass(setup.n_username, setup.n_password,
                                              setup.n_url, setup.n_port, setup.db_password,
                                              username=request.user.username)  

      report = my_object.report_final   # get from variable, not from function.
```